# Pressing 2 keys, release 1, produces keydown of other key again

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I press S, followed by D, on my keyboard, and release S. Why does the following code trigger a key down event for D once again, after I release S? Is there some way to find out that the second down event for D was caused by a key up of another key?

```js
function handler(event) {
  if (!event.repeat) console.log(event.code, event.type);
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
window.addEventListener('keyup', handler);
```

Output:

```
KeyS keydown - S pressed
KeyD keydown - D pressed
KeyS keyup   - S released
KeyD keydown - WHY???
```

The strange keydown event only happens in **Chrome** (I'm using Chromium 66.0.3359.139 on Linux Mint), this does not happen in Firefox.

Might this actually be a bug, or is it intended behavior?

Comment: Interesting, doesn't happen to me in Chrome 66 on Linux... EDIT oh it does but I have to hold it longer!

Comment: Possibly a bug then. I'll report it to the Chrome developers then.

Comment: Pretty sure this is expected behaviour

Comment: I opened a Chromium issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=843558