# an issue with keyDown event in different browsers

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, keydown

so the thing is that 'keydown' event calls after the keyup event if multiple keys are pressed and released in particular order in chrome, but seems like there is no such issue in firefox browser

for example we have these events on window with `if (e.repeat) return` to prevent repeat

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.repeat) return
    console.log(e.key, 'pressed')
})

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    console.log(e.key, 'released')
})
```

and here is the result of me pressing multiple keys at once and then releasing them one by one

[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBzIj.png)

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lqB9.png)

any ideas of how to fix this? i think it has something to do with `if (e.repeat) return` and there is a better way to prevent this event repeat on button hold

Comment: It looks like the events are fired as expected in both of the mentioned browsers ..?

Comment: The code example executed in firefox browser is how it supposed to work.
In chrome, however, i'm getting these extra presses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by Chromium bug, has been open for 5 years: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=843558

See also: [Pressing 2 keys, release 1, produces keydown of other key again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372849/pressing-2-keys-release-1-produces-keydown-of-other-key-again)

Answer (score -1):

I tried doing it on Chrome and Firefox, and it worked as predicted in both of them.
Could you please say what environment you are using this piece of code on?

Comment: Please don't post comments as an answer.

Comment: just VScode and hosting with live server plugin for it

Comment: @Teemu I wasn't autorized to leave a comment. I needed some reputation credit or so.

Comment: @Svygzhryr I used the exact setup and got the result just right.

Comment: @noviceGuru now that's weird

Comment: @noviceGuru i believe you should do it slowly, hold it like 1-2 seconds

Comment: Responses which have exclusively qualifying questions are reserved for the comments section. Its ok to post your answer with these questions, but its best to provide supporting information and provide answers given assumptions. In you're case, rather than ask what environment the OP has, you could have provided answers assuming cited envs yourself. I.E. if your env is X, then you can try Y.