# Why does an extra event fire when two keys are held down and the first key is released?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

This has been plaguing me for some time. I'm using the WebAudioAPI in Javascript to make a synthesizer. I have a keydown event that plays a sound and a keyup event that stops the sound. However, if I hold down two keys, lets say a q first and a w second, if I let go of the q (keeping the w held down), the event for w fires a second time, leaving me with an additional sound playing that never ends even after the keyup event is fired.

This is the keydown event:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if(e.repeat){
                return;
            }

            else if (this.heldKeys.length > 0){
                let keyIsHeld;
                for (let key of this.heldKeys){
                    if (key.code == e.code){
                        this.eventStop(key, true);
                        keyIsHeld = true;
                    }
                }
                if(keyIsHeld){
                    this.removeElementsFromArrayByProperty(this.heldKeys, e);
                }
            }

            this.eventStart(e, true);
            this.heldKeys.push(e);
        });
```

Note the `if (e.repeat)` clause. This works great for holding the key down and not making duplicates, but as soon as another key is pressed down, and that first key is released, oh boy, we get another event fired.

I've tried to implement several ways of catching these duplicate sounds (like the else if statement you can see above), but even when it works (which it doesn't here), the event still fires and there is an interruption in the sound.

I've done a fair bit of googling but all I come back with is to either add the `e.repeat` statement (or something very similar with a bool for a key being pressed), but neither of these have the power to stop the invisible (but loud) man at the dinner, who barges his way in every single time two keys are played and the first is let go.

I hope there's a very obvious answer to this, like maybe with html elements but I cannot fathom what could be making two events fire for the price of one key pressed (with the helping hand of its predecessor).

I have tried this with more than one keyboard btw. Same result.

This is the keydown event if it at all helps:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
            this.eventStop(e, true);
            this.removeElementsFromArrayByProperty(this.heldKeys, e);
        });
```

Here's a Stack Snippet you can use to replicate the events I'm getting:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (!e.repeat) {
        console.log(e.type, e.key);
    }
});
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    console.log(e.type, e.key);
});
```

```html
To replicate:
<ol>
    <li>Click here to focus the document</li>
    <li>Press and hold <kbd>q</kbd></li>
    <li>Press and hold <kbd>w</kbd></li>
    <li>Let go of <kbd>q</kbd></li>
</ol>
After the <code>keyup</code> for <kbd>q</kbd>, there's a spurious non-repeat <code>keydown</code> for <kbd>w</kbd>.
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, that's interesting and it happens to me in Chrome/Chromium but not Firefox. I've added a runnable Stack Snippet to the end that replicates what I think you're describing. Please double-check it to make sure I have that right. If I don't, please just use the rollback feature to undo the edit (you can do that by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77050310/revisions) and then clicking "rollback" in the bar above Phil's formatting edit).

Comment: It `this` what you expect it to be? The `this` is not the same in arrow functions as in event listeners using the function keyword. You might be in luck here since `this` is likely window

Comment: There seems to be a bug ticket posted for Chromium [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=843558) originally from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50372849/7393478). The SO post seems to confirm this is a chromium-only behavior

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah that's the crux of what I want to achieve, but of course, the issue persists as you've discovered (I've been using chrome to test all of this). This example of a synth [here](https://iamschulz.github.io/js-synth/) can be played on Chrome with no sign of this issue. I'm wondering what they're doing that I could implement to circumvent this chrome-specific issue...

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks for finding that! The user jd01 hints that the e.repeat remains true for a keydown until any keyup event is fired. So lifting up that first key while the second key is held down turns e's repeat bool to false, then back to true as long as it's held from that point onward. As I said to TJ, this [synth](https://iamschulz.github.io/js-synth/) while run in chrome seems to have no issues whatsoever regarding this, and I cannot tell exactly how they've managed to circumvent this issue. But that post has helped me to understand the problem a lot better!

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah it's what I want it to be. What's depicted above all runs to refer to members of the Synth class

Comment: @JackGrbovic Seems they are using a different concept in that other synth: https://github.com/iamschulz/js-synth

Comment: Here is an online keyboard event tester, which you can run in your various browser: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/d4e/raw-file/tip/key-event-test.html Shows key up/down evnts and much more

Answer (score 0):

Bearing in mind what @Kaddath showed us, that the `repeat` property of an event gets set to `false` when the key that triggers it is held down, while another key is also held down and lifted up to fire its `keyup` event; I edited the `keyup` and `keydown` event handlers so that the `keydown` returns when this additional event is fired.

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            let isKeyAlreadyPressed;
            for (let key of this.heldKeys){
                if (key.code == e.code){
                    isKeyAlreadyPressed = true;
                }
            }
            if(e.repeat || isKeyAlreadyPressed){
                return;
            }
            else{
                this.eventStart(e, true);
                this.heldKeys.push(e);
            }
        });

        document.body.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
            this.eventStop(e, true);
            this.heldKeys = this.removeElementsFromArrayByProperty(this.heldKeys, "code", e.code);
        });
```

At the end of the `keydown` event, we add the event to an array called `heldKeys`.

In `keyUp`, every element in the `heldKeys` array that has the same `code` property as `e` is removed from the array, so we know it's no longer being held down.

When `keyDown` is next fired, we check to see if there is an event in `heldKeys` that has a `code` matching `e`'s `code`. If that is true, there is already a key of the same type being held down, so when this additional event fires, it is prevented from ruining our ears with its never ending surplus sound.

It's not a proper proper fix, but I've not actually seen anyone post a solution to it so I wanted to post this here in case anyone might want a quick remedy to a similar issue.

[Here's the project](https://visionary-khapse-13c681.netlify.app/) btw (mostly finished, currently restructuring for React and TypeScript).