Keydown firing twice when the previous keydown was held
In my web app, for reasons I don't know yet, whenever I hold down a key for about more than half a second, (more reliably replicable when held for 2 seconds), the next key I press (given that I press it while holding the other key down, and rapidly unpress the previous key), the new key pressed will fire twice, without the repeat property being true. this is the JavaScript code I use, which requires minimal HTML boilerplating
window.bin = false;
window.events = [];
document.addEventListener("mousedown", ()=>{
    console.log("start listening for keys");
    document.addEventListener("keydown", e=>{
        if (e.repeat) return;
        console.log(e);
        events.push(e);
        console.log(bin = !bin); //make it easier to tell that they are different events firing?
    });
}, {once: true});

Here's a small diagram of what I'm doing with my keyboard. The X axis represents the progression of time, and the Y axis serves solely to show where key pressed overlap.
Each Keypress would last 2 seconds to get the most accuracy of replication.
X [ "A" Key ]     [ "C" Key ]
X         [ "B" Key ]     [ "D" Key ]

if I was to emulate this diagram in keypresses, My browser would display the following in the log
KeyBoardEvent properties that are the same:
isTrusted: true
altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
charCode: 0
--------------------
composed: true
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
isComposing: false
--------------------
--------------------
location: 0
metaKey: false
repeat: false
returnValue: true
shiftKey: false
sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities {firesTouchEvents: false}
srcElement: HTMLBodyElement
target: HTMLBodyElement
--------------------
type: "keydown"
view: Window

Simplified Log
> KeyboardEvent {code: "KeyA", key: "a", keyCode: 65, which: 65, timestamp: 6884.599999997765} 
> true
> KeyboardEvent {code: "KeyB", key: "b", keyCode: 66, which: 66, timestamp: 8024.89999999851} 
> false
> KeyboardEvent {code: "KeyB", key: "b", keyCode: 66, which: 66, timestamp: 8324.89999999851} 
> true
> KeyboardEvent {code: "KeyC", key: "c", keyCode: 67, which: 67, timestamp: 9139.699999999255}
> false
> KeyboardEvent {code: "KeyC", key: "c", keyCode: 67, which: 67, timestamp: 9439.800000000745} 
> true
> KeyboardEvent {code: "KeyD", key: "d", keyCode: 68, which: 68, timestamp: 10238.5} 
> false
> KeyboardEvent {code: "KeyD", key: "d", keyCode: 68, which: 68, timestamp: 10539.699999999255} 
> true

My Browser is Chrome Beta 127.0.6533.94 on ChromeOS. Sorry in advance if the question gives too much unnecessary information, or if this is just a bug.
Edit: it is, but issue is not popular enough to be fixed. related:

Pressing 2 keys, release 1, produces keydown of other key again
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41389310


Did you try same with another physical keyboard?

Unfortunately not, sorry. I don't have access to more than what I do. I'm just trying to figure out why it's happening and if it is supposed to happen.

Did you click multiple times?

@DanielA.White no. When I reload or start the page, I simply Press Ctrl+Shift+I (why I wanted to click first and then get keydowns), and then I click on the document to start listening for events to log. from there, I start mashing A,B,C,D, and etc.

Does the Chromebook have a "power saving" setting and, if so, does turning it off make any difference? This vaguely reminds me of a very cheap wireless keyboard that would turn itself off after a few seconds of inactivity.

@traktor "Battery Saving" is and was disabled, and messing with it does nothing to help this issue. Thanks anyway.

I tested this myself in both Chrome and Firefox, and it seems that only Chrome has this issue.
Releasing a key on Chrome fires a keyup event (as expected), but this also resets the repeat flag on the key that was being held down beforehand. This causes another keydown event to be fired, but this time with repeat: false, thus registering as another keydown event in your code.
Below a small test that shows this, first 2 events have repeat: true, thus should not be registered as a keystroke by your code. When the other key is released, it causes the next event to have repeat: false, thus registering a new keystroke.

You could try to circumvent this problem by specifically listening to a keyup event for the key that is being held down, if there is no keyup event between 2 of the same keydown events, then you know it is not a legitimate keystroke.
I don't know why Chrome has this behaviour, as it does not seem intended.

Should this be reported a bug, you think?

I think it's definitely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/50372849 keywords were different but I found it after looking up a crbug for "keydown fired more than once" and stumbled across https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41389310

Good find! Yeah definitely the same problem, I saw you revived the thread, but I'm doubtful that anything will be done to fix it, as it hasn't for 6 years it seems.
